# How to change styling on rails-generated outputs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, asset-pipeline

I am using twitter bootstrap installed by copying bootstrap.min.css, etc. into the vendor/assets folder.

When using rails forms validations, error messages appear using default styling, not the bootstrap styling I would expect (e.g. the h2 tag is much smaller and in a different text, the unordered list uses different bullets, etc.) How do I get bootstrap to override the default styling that rails uses when generating error messages for forms?  I'm guessing this has something to do with the asset pipeline, but didn't see anything about overriding rails-generated content in the [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you used some scaffolding which generated a CSS sheet. Go into app/assets/stylesheets and delete the stylesheet named "scaffolds.scss" (or just delete the parts you don't want).

Comment: Worked perfectly!  Will come back and upvote once I have the reputation.

Comment: Thanks :) You should also mark the answer as correct since it work

Answer (score 0):

To track down where that styling is coming from, you should use your browsers development tools. Inspect the element and it should tell you where the styling is coming from.
[image: inspect element]